# Using RowEditing and CheckBoxSelectionModel in a Grid Fails

Tags: gxt

In a GXT `Grid` I am attempting to use `RowEditing` and the `CheckBoxSelectionModel`. The Sencha Explorer Demo has examples of these in the [Row Editable Grid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:roweditablegrid) and [CheckBox Grid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:checkboxgrid) samples, but they don't show an example that includes a combination of these features. When I use both features on the same grid I am not getting the behavior that I had expected. If I click on the "selection" checkbox the row is placed into edit mode, where I would have expected the checkbox to just change from checked to unchecked or vice versa. In addition, when the row is placed into edit mode there is corruption on the line. Here is an example of a row from the grid prior to clicking on any of the values in that row:

[image]

and here is that row after clicking on one of the values:

[image]

Does anyone have any experience with this?

**Update**

Here's a sample class which demonstrates the issue:

```java
package org.greatlogic.gxtgrid.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.IdentityValueProvider;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.ValueProvider;
import com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ListStore;
import com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ModelKeyProvider;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.ContentPanel;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.TextField;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.CheckBoxSelectionModel;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnConfig;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnModel;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.Grid;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.GridView;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.editing.GridRowEditing;

public class GXTGrid implements EntryPoint {
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
  ListStore<Pet> listStore = new ListStore<>(new ModelKeyProvider<Pet>() {
    @Override
    public String getKey(Pet pet) {
      return Integer.toString(pet.getPetId());
    }
  });
  IdentityValueProvider<Pet> ivp = new IdentityValueProvider<>();
  CheckBoxSelectionModel<Pet> sm = new CheckBoxSelectionModel<>(ivp);
  ArrayList<ColumnConfig<Pet, ?>> ccList = new ArrayList<>();
  ccList.add(sm.getColumn());
  ColumnConfig<Pet, String> cc1;
  cc1 = new ColumnConfig<>(Pet.getPetNameValueProvider(), 100, "Name");
  ccList.add(cc1);
  ColumnModel<Pet> columnModel = new ColumnModel<>(ccList);
  Grid<Pet> grid = new Grid<>(listStore, columnModel);
  grid.setSelectionModel(sm);
  grid.setView(new GridView<Pet>());
  GridRowEditing<Pet> gre = new GridRowEditing<>(grid);
  gre.addEditor(cc1, new TextField());
  listStore.add(new Pet(1, "Lassie"));
  listStore.add(new Pet(2, "Scooby"));
  listStore.add(new Pet(3, "Snoopy"));
  ContentPanel contentPanel = new ContentPanel();
  contentPanel.add(grid);
  RootLayoutPanel.get().add(contentPanel);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
private static class Pet {
private int _petId;
private String    _petName;
public static ValueProvider<Pet, String> getPetNameValueProvider() {
  return new ValueProvider<Pet, String>() {
    @Override
    public String getPath() {
      return "Pet.PetName";
    }
    @Override
    public String getValue(Pet pet) {
      return pet._petName;
    }
    @Override
    public void setValue(Pet pet, final String value) {
      pet._petName = value;
    }
  };
}
public Pet(int petId, final String petName) {
  _petId = petId;
  _petName = petName;
}
public int getPetId() {
  return _petId;
}
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code? You would get more and better answers.

Comment: @RadASM The code is fairly extensive, but you can just take the Sencha Row Editable Grid example in the [Sencha GXT Explorer Demo](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:roweditablegrid) and add the `CheckBoxSelectionModel` to it to see the problem. Have you had success with a grid that uses `RowEditing` combined with the `CheckBoxSelectModel` option?

Comment: I am used to inlineRowEditing. So basically as I have been working with gxt for a while I might be able to help. One idea that may help you (not to solve but to avoid the problem) is not to start edition on one click on cell but on double click. 
     gridRowEditing.setClicksToEdit(ClicksToEdit.TWO);
I am sorry but without seeing source code I don't think I can give you more help.

Comment: @RadASM Thank you ... I'll create a (relatively) small test case and update my question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a solution to this problem using the `CheckBoxSelectionModel`, and so I decided to try another approach, namely, adding a column to the grid that contains a checkbox, and handling the state of the selections manually. To do this I found that I needed to respond to a few events, which wasn't too bad. Here's a new version of the sample code, which should provide a starting point for a real implementation:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;
import com.sencha.gxt.cell.core.client.form.CheckBoxCell;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.ValueProvider;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.dom.XElement;
import com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ListStore;
import com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ModelKeyProvider;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.ContentPanel;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.CheckBox;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.Field;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.TextField;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.CellSelectionModel;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnConfig;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnModel;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.Grid;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.GridView;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.editing.GridRowEditing;

public class GXTGrid implements EntryPoint {
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
private ListStore<Pet>   _listStore;
private TreeSet<Integer> _selectedPetIdSet;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
  _selectedPetIdSet = new TreeSet<>();
  _listStore = new ListStore<>(new ModelKeyProvider<Pet>() {
    @Override
    public String getKey(Pet pet) {
      return Integer.toString(pet.getPetId());
    }
  });
  final CellSelectionModel<Pet> sm = new CellSelectionModel<>();
  ArrayList<ColumnConfig<Pet, ?>> ccList = new ArrayList<>();
  ValueProvider<Pet, Boolean> selectValueProvider;
  selectValueProvider = new ValueProvider<GXTGrid.Pet, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public String getPath() {
      return "SelectCheckBox";
    }
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue(Pet pet) {
      return _selectedPetIdSet.contains(pet.getPetId());
    }
    @Override
    public void setValue(Pet pet, final Boolean selected) { //
    }
  };
  ColumnConfig<Pet, Boolean> cc0 = new ColumnConfig<>(selectValueProvider, 23, "");
  CheckBoxCell checkBoxCell = new CheckBoxCell() {
    @Override
    protected void onClick(XElement parent, final NativeEvent event) {
      super.onClick(parent, event);
      Pet pet = sm.getSelectedItem();
      if (!_selectedPetIdSet.remove(pet.getPetId())) {
        _selectedPetIdSet.add(pet.getPetId());
      }
    }
  };
  cc0.setCell(checkBoxCell);
  cc0.setFixed(true);
  cc0.setHideable(false);
  cc0.setMenuDisabled(true);
  cc0.setResizable(false);
  cc0.setSortable(false);
  ccList.add(cc0);
  ColumnConfig<Pet, String> cc1;
  cc1 = new ColumnConfig<>(Pet.getPetNameValueProvider(), 100, "Name");
  ccList.add(cc1);
  ColumnModel<Pet> columnModel = new ColumnModel<>(ccList);
  Grid<Pet> grid = new Grid<>(_listStore, columnModel);
  grid.setSelectionModel(sm);
  grid.setView(new GridView<Pet>());
  GridRowEditing<Pet> gre = new GridRowEditing<>(grid);
  Field<Boolean> checkBox = new CheckBox();
  checkBox.setEnabled(false);
  gre.addEditor(cc0, checkBox);
  gre.addEditor(cc1, new TextField());
  _listStore.add(new Pet(1, "Lassie"));
  _listStore.add(new Pet(2, "Scooby"));
  _listStore.add(new Pet(3, "Snoopy"));
  ContentPanel contentPanel = new ContentPanel();
  contentPanel.add(grid);
  RootLayoutPanel.get().add(contentPanel);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
private static class Pet {
private int _petId;
private String    _petName;
public static ValueProvider<Pet, String> getPetNameValueProvider() {
  return new ValueProvider<Pet, String>() {
    @Override
    public String getPath() {
      return "Pet.PetName";
    }
    @Override
    public String getValue(Pet pet) {
      return pet._petName;
    }
    @Override
    public void setValue(Pet pet, final String value) {
      pet._petName = value;
    }
  };
}
public Pet(int petId, final String petName) {
  _petId = petId;
  _petName = petName;
}
public int getPetId() {
  return _petId;
}
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: Does it also solve the problem with the display of toString  in beginning of the row?

Comment: Yes, because there is now a `CheckBox` field at the start of the line in edit mode. Note that I have just changed the code to simply disable this checkbox in edit mode, which significantly simplifies the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior of GridRowEditing with CheckBoxSelectionModel is completely normal.

I have used you code to try some things. I think the best way to use `GridRowEditing` and `CheckBoxSelectionModel` is, as I guessed, to start editing on double click, as nothing is provided to do it with just one click yet. To do so just add

```
gre.setClicksToEdit(ClicksToEdit.TWO);
```

Otherwise, if you really do not want to use two clicks to start editing, you can also use `InlineRowEditing`, which will enable you to use `CheckBoxSelectionModel` as you want.

Eventually, you might be able to override the whole behavior of `GridRowEditing` to handle CheckBoxSelectionModel properly on one click only, but it would be more complicated and require more specific knowledge of GXT framework that I don't have.

Comment: I tried adding `setClicksToEdit(ClicksToEdit.TWO)` and I see the same behavior (of course, I have to click twice now to enter edit mode). The beginning of the row is "corrupt" ... it displays the `toString` of the record, which in my case is the default `Object#toString`. This behavior is consistent whether I have one or two click editing. I could probably live with this behavior, except that the fields used for editing don't line up with the columns. Anyway, thanks again for your help!